# <p> tag id style not respected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to change style for 'id=koll' but the css file still reads the style info for 'id=koll' from '#kava p'

```css
#kava p {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin-top: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#koll {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id='kava'>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h4>title</h4>
      <p id="koll">sdsd sdg s sdfsdf</p>
      <p>sldfhs sdfh sd sdufhs f sdufhsd</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: use this css: #kava p#koll {font-weight: 400;font-size: 1.2rem;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because of strong inheritance.

```css
#kava p {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin-top: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#kava #koll {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id='kava'>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h4>title</h4>
      <p id="koll">sdsd sdg s sdfsdf</p>
      <p>sldfhs sdfh sd sdufhs f sdufhsd</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not about inheritance but specificity

Comment: Thanks, that worked :)